# How do I run (debug) WCF REST Service application on local IIS7 server

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7

As the question says, I have a problem running the web app on local IIS.

Here is my situation:

- WIndows over Oracle VM VirtualBox running on Linux Ubuntu.
- Bridged Adapter so that Windows box gets local IP from my router.
- Visual Studio 2010 + sp
- WCF REST Service application plugin for project template
- The application runs when using visual studio development server (on localhost).
- Target framework is v4.0

What I need is that the application runs on IP instead on localhost (so I can consume it on remote computer in LAN), so I configured IIS7.

Here is IIS configuration:

- I created a website with target framework v.4.0
- I binded the site to my local IP on port 80
- Path to the site is /inetpub/wwwroot iisstart.htm as default document
- IIS runs ok. If I open "http://my_local_ip" I get the welcome logo.

The problem is in visual studio.

When I go to project properties "Web" section and select local IIS over vsd server is where I get lost. If I set "Project URL" to "http://my_local_ip/some_name" visual studio complains that it cannot find IIS server and so it was unable to create the virtual directory. I tried manually adding virtual directory in IIS manager, but no effect. If I use "http://localhost/some_name" as the "Project URL" the virtual directory gets created, but it makes no sense does it?

Could some one please enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use "http://localhost/some_name" as the "Project URL" the virtual directory gets created, but it makes no sense does it?

I think you are mixing two different things here. When you ask VS to use localhost as the IIS Server for your project, it will connect to the local IIS to perform configuration tasks. If you ask VS to use "my_local_ip" you are telling VS that you IIS Server is remote, and therefore VS will use remote administration to configure IIS (VS can't know that my_local_ip is the local computer).

But remote IIS admin isn't enabled on a default WinServer box. Furthermore, it would require some additionnal network config. You should therefore tell vs to use the local server.

In fact, IIS site bindings and VS deployment parameters are too completely different things. So, deploy your site on http://localhost/your_site.

However, I don't really like the prospect of using VS debugging deploy to deploy a real app. The directory will contain all your project files... You should:

1. create your site on IIS manager and setup a virtual directory.
2. Either

   - ask VS to publish the site to a directory (your virtual directory)
   - ask VS to publish a WebDeploy package, then ask IIS manager to import the package.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Eilistraee. Yet i dont understand your proposal (i am new in ISS). I created a virtual directory on my webpage in ISS manager with alias "service" and set physical path to /inetpub/wwwroot/service. If i understand, VS should copy the files to this directory once i build/run the app? Well in VS i then chose local IIS and "Project URL" as "http://localhost/service". VS somehow does not know that virtual directory was already created and it fails trying to create one... Sorry, but i really never done this before!

Comment: Ok i somehow created the virtual directory so that VS is happy with it. Details of virtual directory are: I created a folder /inetpub/wwwroot/service and set this folder as a physical path of the virtual directory. The alias is service. Using this in VS gives me no error. But when i run the app VS throws an error: Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server could not find the requested resource. What am i missing?

Comment: ok some progress was made earlyer. I was able to publish the application on IIS. In the virtual directory i now have bin folder, global.asax and web.config. All i need now is figure out why IIS wont run the application. Currently it demands that i set default document or enable directory browsing, but ofcorse thats not my goal.

Comment: Debugging and deploying are really two different things. What VS do when you start your app for debugging is only "attaching the debugger to w3wp.exe" if IIS debugging was chosen. And when you configure your project to use IIS debugging, VS will create a virtual directory bound to your project directory. The point is: You don't need VS to run a Web app hosted on IIS. If you don't want to mix production and debugging, you could install IISExpress, available through web platform installer.

Comment: I know the difference Eilistraee, but thanks for explaining. I was OK with the fact to "deploy" the application just for the sole purpose of getting able to consume the services on my linux box, where im developing Android application. I went with IISExpress as you suggestes and created the site as http://my_hostname:80. It debugs from VS on the windows box with no error. Do you happen to know what i must do to be able to access that site from my linux box that is in same LAN?

Comment: PS: I followed instructions from http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx but im unable to access the site from another box in LAN.

Comment: works ok. I had to fix /etc/hosts and is runing ok. Thank you !